# How to calculate interquartile mean of an array in swift?

Tags: ios, swift

From [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interquartile_mean):

> The interquartile mean (IQM) (or midmean) is a statistical measure of
>   central tendency based on the truncated mean of the interquartile
>   range. The IQM is very similar to the scoring method used in sports
>   that are evaluated by a panel of judges: discard the lowest and the
>   highest scores; calculate the mean value of the remaining scores.
>
> In calculation of the IQM, only the data in the second and third
>   quartiles is used (as in the interquartile range), and the lowest 25%
>   and the highest 25% of the scores are discarded. These points are
>   called the first and third quartiles, hence the name of the IQM. (Note
>   that the second quartile is also called the median).

Answer (score 2):

```
func interquartile_mean(array: [Double]) -> Double {
    let sorted_array = array.sort()
    let from = Int(array.count*1/4)
    let to = Int(array.count*3/4)
    return Array(sorted_array[from..<to]).average
}
extension Array where Element: DoubleConvertible {
    var total: Element {
        return  Element(reduce(0){ $0 + $1.double })
    }
    var average: Element {
        return  isEmpty ? Element(0) : Element(total.double / Double(count))
    }
}
```

Comment: You can also create an extension of a double array that returns the interquartile_mean if it is more convenient...